# text align issue in a table

Tags: alignment

I have a free wordpress template which I am sure will limit my ability to do anything.  However, here goes.

If you visit [this page](http://hamabeadpatterns.co.uk/hama-beads/midi-beads-5/disney-gift-sets/) you will see that I have a table and the text in column 2 appears well below the image in column 1.  I've tried the things I believe I know (please note that is very limited knowledge) but can not get it to align to the left.

I'd like the text in column 2 to start from the top left of the box it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i don't know much of Wordpress but the problem is that your text have the css property

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

so you must set it to

```
vertical-align: top;
```

I repeat, i don't know how to apply in Wordpress but if you can put this in the cell,  it will works

```
 <td style="vertical-align: top">...</td>
```

Comment: Roberto.  Thank you ever so much.  I am very, very grateful for your help.